# DjangoUnicodeDecodeError while running makemigrations

Tags: python, django

I'll post my models below, but please note that I'm using the 'u' prefix everywhere, and I've added the magic encoding line as the second line of my file. I'm using django 1.9 and python 2.7

**MODEL**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Organisaatio(models.Model):
    organisaation_nimi = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_(u"Organisaation nimi"),
        max_length=128,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text=_(u"Organisaatiosi nimi"),
        )

    organisaation_koko = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name=_(u"Organisaation Koko"),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text=_(u"Arvio organisaatiosi jäsenmaräästä"),
        )

    kuvaus = models.TextField(
        verbose_name=_(u"Tehtävän kuvaus"),
        blank=True,
        default="",
        help_text=_(u"Kuvaile tehtävää"),
        )

    kesto = models.DecimalField(
        verbose_name=_(u"Tehtävään käytetty aika"),
        max_digits = 3,
        decimal_places=2,
        null=True,
        help_text=_(u"Arvioi tunneissa, kuinka kauan tehtävään käytetään keskimäärin aikaa"),
        )

    kertaa = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name=_(u"Kertaa per kuukausi"),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text=_(u"Arvioi kuinka monta kertaa kuukauden aikana tehtävä tehdään")
        )


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.organisaation_nimi
```

After running the makemigrations command, it starts to create the make-file:

```
 Migrations for 'app':
  0002_auto_20170809_1628.py:
    - Create model Kysymys
    - Add field kertaa to organisaatio
    - Add field kesto to organisaatio
    - Add field kuvaus to organisaatio
    - Alter field organisaation_koko on organisaatio
    - Alter field organisaation_nimi on organisaatio
```

and then spits out an unicode error:

```
django.utils.encoding.DjangoUnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 21: ordinal not in range(128). You passed in 
<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x109ba0ad0> (<class 
'django.utils.functional.__proxy__'>)
```

I'm perplexed, as I've asserted the coding at the top of the file, and I'm using the u prefix everywhere.

Thanks for your time!

**EDIT**

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 150, in handle
    self.write_migration_files(changes)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 178, in write_migration_files
    migration_string = writer.as_string()
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 167, in as_string
    operation_string, operation_imports = OperationWriter(operation).serialize()
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 124, in serialize
    _write(arg_name, arg_value)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 76, in _write
    arg_string, arg_imports = MigrationWriter.serialize(item)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 357, in serialize
    item_string, item_imports = cls.serialize(item)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 433, in serialize
    return cls.serialize_deconstructed(path, args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 318, in serialize_deconstructed
    arg_string, arg_imports = cls.serialize(arg)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 346, in serialize
    value = force_text(value)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 88, in force_text
    raise DjangoUnicodeDecodeError(s, *e.args)
django.utils.encoding.DjangoUnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 21: ordinal not in range(128). You passed in <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x109898b10> (<class 'django.utils.functional.__proxy__'>)
```

Comment: please, show full trace error

Comment: I've added the full trace now

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your u'...' with b'...'

I use django to auto-create my migrations (with makemigrations) and it tends to default to this.